# Upgrading libpython3.9 removes 231 packages

Tags: apt, python, python3, 21.04

After updating the package lists, a list of upgradable packages has appeared:

```
Listing... Done
libpython3.9-dev/focal 3.9.6-1+focal1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.9.5-3~21.04]
libpython3.9-minimal/focal 3.9.6-1+focal1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.9.5-3~21.04]
libpython3.9-stdlib/focal 3.9.6-1+focal1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.9.5-3~21.04]
libpython3.9/focal 3.9.6-1+focal1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.9.5-3~21.04]
python3.9-dev/focal 3.9.6-1+focal1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.9.5-3~21.04]
python3.9-minimal/focal 3.9.6-1+focal1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.9.5-3~21.04]
python3.9/focal 3.9.6-1+focal1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.9.5-3~21.04]
```

Trying to `upgrade` yields the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libpython3.9-minimal python3.9-minimal
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Now when I try to install `python3.9-minimal`, it says it depends on the newly installable `libpython3.9-minimal`. However, when I try to install `libpython3.9-minimal`, I am proposed to uninstall 231 packages for some reason (probably because those 231 packages require the current `libpython3.9-minimal` package). Is there any other way to fix this?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apg apport-symptoms aptdaemon-data avahi-utils cups-pk-helper dc dctrl-tools dh-translations diffstat distro-info distro-info-data docbook-xml genisoimage
  gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdm-1.0
  gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-graphene-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-4
  gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-handy-0.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 gir1.2-mutter-7
  gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-soup-2.4
  gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0 gir1.2-udisks-2.0 gir1.2-unity-7.0 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gkbd-capplet
  gnome-control-center-faces gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-shell-common gnome-startup-applications gnome-terminal-data gnome-todo-common
  grilo-plugins-0.3-base gstreamer1.0-pipewire ibus-data javascript-common jq libaliased-perl libamtk-5-0 libamtk-5-common libapt-pkg-perl libarray-intspan-perl
  libb-hooks-endofscope-perl libb-hooks-op-check-perl libbabeltrace1 libblkid-dev libboost-regex1.74.0 libc6-dbg libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcapture-tiny-perl
  libclang-cpp12 libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-method-modifiers-perl libclass-xsaccessor-perl libcolord-gtk1 libcommon-sense-perl libconfig-tiny-perl
  libconst-fast-perl libcontextual-return-perl libcpanel-json-xs-perl libdata-dpath-perl libdata-messagepack-perl libdata-optlist-perl libdata-validate-domain-perl
  libdatrie-dev libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev-bin libdebuginfod-common libdebuginfod1 libdevel-callchecker-perl libdevel-size-perl libdevel-stacktrace-perl
  libdistro-info-perl libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdynaloader-functions-perl libegl-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libemail-address-xs-perl libepoxy-dev libexception-class-perl
  libexporter-tiny-perl libfdk-aac2 libfile-chdir-perl libfile-dirlist-perl libfile-find-rule-perl libfile-homedir-perl libfile-touch-perl libfile-which-perl
  libfont-ttf-perl libfribidi-dev libgetopt-long-descriptive-perl libgit-wrapper-perl libgitlab-api-v4-perl libgles-dev libgles1 libglvnd-dev libgnome-todo
  libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgom-1.0-0 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgraphite2-dev libgrilo-0.3-0 libgsound0 libgssdp-1.2-0 libgupnp-1.2-0 libgupnp-av-1.0-2
  libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libharfbuzz-gobject0 libhash-fieldhash-perl libhpmud0 libhtml-html5-entities-perl libhttp-tiny-multipart-perl libimagequant0
  libimport-into-perl libio-prompter-perl libio-pty-perl libio-string-perl libipc-run-perl libipc-run3-perl libipt2 libiterator-perl libiterator-util-perl libjq1
  libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libjson-maybexs-perl libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl libkeybinder-3.0-0 libldb2 liblist-compare-perl
  liblist-moreutils-perl liblist-moreutils-xs-perl liblist-someutils-perl liblist-someutils-xs-perl liblist-utilsby-perl liblog-any-adapter-screen-perl
  liblog-any-perl libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libmarkdown2 libmbedcrypto3 libmbedtls12 libmbedx509-0 libmediaart-2.0-0 libmodule-implementation-perl
  libmodule-runtime-perl libmoo-perl libmoox-aliases-perl libmoox-struct-perl libmount-dev libmouse-perl libmpdec3 libmtdev-dev libmutter-7-0
  libnamespace-autoclean-perl libnamespace-clean-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl libnetplan0 libnumber-compare-perl libnumber-range-perl libnvidia-cfg1-465
  libnvidia-common-465 libnvidia-decode-465 libnvidia-encode-465 libnvidia-extra-465 libnvidia-fbc1-465 libnvidia-gl-465 libnvidia-ifr1-465 libobject-id-perl
  libobrender32v5 libobt2v5 libonig5 libopengl-dev libopengl0 libpackage-stash-perl libpackage-stash-xs-perl libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl
  libparams-validate-perl libpath-iterator-rule-perl libpath-tiny-perl libpcre16-3 libpcre2-dev libpcre2-posix2 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpeas-common
  libperlio-gzip-perl libpixman-1-dev libpod-constants-perl libpod-parser-perl libproc-processtable-perl libqt5xml5 libre-engine-re2-perl libre2-9 libreadonly-perl
  libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl libregexp-pattern-license-perl libregexp-pattern-perl librole-tiny-perl librsync2 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2
  librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libsane-hpaio libselinux1-dev libsepol1-dev libsereal-decoder-perl libsereal-encoder-perl libsgutils2-2
  libsort-key-perl libsort-versions-perl libsource-highlight-common libsource-highlight4v5 libstartup-notification0 libstrictures-perl libstring-copyright-perl
  libstring-escape-perl libstring-shellquote-perl libsub-exporter-perl libsub-exporter-progressive-perl libsub-identify-perl libsub-install-perl libsub-quote-perl
  libtalloc2 libtepl-5-0 libterm-readkey-perl libtevent0 libtext-glob-perl libtext-levenshteinxs-perl libtext-markdown-discount-perl libtext-xslate-perl libthai-dev
  libtime-duration-perl libtime-moment-perl libtorrent-rasterbar10 libtype-tiny-perl libtype-tiny-xs-perl libtypes-serialiser-perl libunicode-utf8-perl
  libvariable-magic-perl libvncserver1 libwant-perl libwbclient0 libwhoopsie-preferences0 libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common libxatracker2 libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-res0
  libxcb-shm0-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxinerama-dev libxklavier16 libxnvctrl0 libxrandr-dev libxres1 libxvmc1 libyaml-libyaml-perl
  libyelp0 libz3-4 libz3-dev licensecheck lintian media-player-info mobile-broadband-provider-info mscompress mutter-common network-manager-gnome
  nvidia-compute-utils-465 nvidia-kernel-common-465 nvidia-kernel-source-465 nvidia-utils-465 obconf obsession pango1.0-tools patchutils plymouth-label
  policykit-1-gnome power-profiles-daemon printer-driver-hpcups python-apt-common python-pip-whl python3-minimal python3.9-minimal rhythmbox-data rygel
  session-migration sgml-base sgml-data switcheroo-control t1utils totem-common vim-runtime wayland-protocols whoopsie-preferences x11-apps x11-session-utils
  x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev xbitmaps xbrlapi xfonts-scalable xinit xinput xml-core xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-legacy xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-465 xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-radeon
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xwayland yelp-xsl
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  policykit-1-gnome python3.9-minimal
Recommended packages:
  libpython3.9-stdlib python3.9
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apport apport-gtk aptdaemon apturl apturl-common cdbs chrome-gnome-shell command-not-found deja-dup devscripts dkms dput duplicity eog firefox
  foomatic-db-compressed-ppds gdb gdm3 gedit gedit-common gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gnome-control-center gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-menus
  gnome-online-accounts gnome-remote-desktop gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng gnome-shell-extension-prefs
  gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-terminal gnome-todo gnome-tweaks gnome-user-docs gvfs-backends hplip hplip-data ibus ibus-table kazam
  language-selector-common language-selector-gnome libappindicator3-dev libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatk1.0-dev libatspi2.0-dev libcairo2-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev
  libdbusmenu-glib-dev libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgtk-3-dev libgudev-1.0-dev libharfbuzz-dev libinput-dev libpango1.0-dev
  libpeas-1.0-0 libpulse-dev libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.9 libpython3.9-dev libpython3.9-stdlib librhythmbox-core10 libsmbclient libspeechd-dev
  libtotem0 libwacom-dev llvm-12-dev llvm-12-tools lsb-release nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal nautilus-share netplan.io networkd-dispatcher nvidia-dkms-465
  nvidia-driver-465 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings obs-studio openbox openprinting-ppds orca plymouth-theme-spinner plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text printer-driver-foo2zjs
  printer-driver-foo2zjs-common printer-driver-m2300w printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr printer-driver-sag-gdi python3
  python3-apport python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-bcrypt python3-blinker python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-certifi
  python3-cffi-backend python3-chardet python3-click python3-colorama python3-commandnotfound python3-cryptography python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-dateutil
  python3-dbus python3-debconf python3-debian python3-defer python3-dev python3-distro python3-distro-info python3-distupgrade python3-distutils python3-fasteners
  python3-future python3-gdbm python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-gpg python3-graphviz python3-httplib2 python3-ibus-1.0 python3-idna python3-jeepney python3-jwt
  python3-keyring python3-launchpadlib python3-lazr.restfulclient python3-lazr.uri python3-ldb python3-lib2to3 python3-lockfile python3-louis python3-macaroonbakery
  python3-magic python3-mako python3-markupsafe python3-monotonic python3-nacl python3-netifaces python3-notify2 python3-oauthlib python3-olefile python3-paramiko
  python3-pexpect python3-pil python3-pip python3-pipdeptree python3-pkg-resources python3-problem-report python3-protobuf python3-ptyprocess python3-pyatspi
  python3-pygments python3-pymacaroons python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-requests python3-rfc3339 python3-scour
  python3-secretstorage python3-setuptools python3-simplejson python3-six python3-software-properties python3-speechd python3-systemd python3-talloc python3-tz
  python3-unidiff python3-uno python3-update-manager python3-urllib3 python3-wadllib python3-wheel python3-xdg python3-xkit python3-yaml python3.9 python3.9-dev
  qbittorrent rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar rhythmbox-plugins samba-libs scour screen-resolution-extra software-properties-common
  software-properties-gtk steam-launcher system-config-printer system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-udev totem totem-plugins ubuntu-advantage-tools
  ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-docs ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-session
  ubuntu-standard ufw unattended-upgrades update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk
  v4l2loopback-dkms vim vlc-plugin-samba xorg xserver-xorg yelp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  policykit-1-gnome
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.9-minimal python3.9-minimal
2 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 231 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2.705 kB of archives.
After this operation, 965 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: Looks like you use Python3.9 as your default python interpreter. Ubuntu 20.04 focal uses python3.8 as default python interpreter. NEVER change the default python interpreter, it will cause many problems to your system.

Comment: The non-standard version numbers of the newer Py3.9 packages suggests that your upgraded packages are from a non-Ubuntu source, and are incompatible with your current Py3.9. That was your second mistake. Delete that non-Ubuntu source.

Comment: @user535733, ok, so the solution is to simply downgrade to an older python version, thank you.

Comment: @yangmandi, I am on ubuntu 21.04 by the way. Isn't Python 3.9 the default version for it?

Comment: @yangmandi, I should be using Python 3.9 on Ubuntu 21.04, my mistake was adding the deadsnakes PPA which interferes with the default package lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had the deadsnakes PPA, which added extra versions of the python3.9 packages, which were incompatible with other packages that required the stock python3.9 packages.